# Context Menu in angular2-tree-component

Tags: angular

Need help in implementing context menu (right click) in angular2-tree-component. Please help in this.I have got the tree working fine. I dont know how to get the IActionMapping functions working.

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to programmatically trigger the context menu on right click.

1. Add a hook for right click by specifying the action mapping in the tree option in your controller:

```js
options: ITreeOptions = {
    actionMapping: {
        mouse: {
            contextMenu: (model: any, node: any, event: any) => {
                this.onContextMenu(event, node.data.name);
                console.log('in context menu...');
            }
        }
    },
};
```

2. Specify this as your tree option in your tree-root:

```html
<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
```

3. trigger the context menu programmatically in the onContextMenu method- I used ngx-contextmenu

Comment: How and where you have defined `onContextMenu`?

Comment: @FurqanSafdar have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-contextmenu